# Disable Tab on the basis of value of another field in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to disable a Tab on the basis of value from another field (two optionset). Basically My objective is If process complete = False then the Tab Sales Process must be disabled. If process complete =True then the Tab Sales Process must be enabled. The Process complete is a two optionset field and the Sales process is a tab. I'm using the below code for disabling all controls in tab. But I'm not able to make it work with the condition of the another field (Two option set)

```
function DisableAllControlsInTab(tabControlNo)
{
    var factfindcontrol=Xrm.Page.getAttribute("processcomplete").getValue();   
      var tabControl = Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("sales process");
   if (factfindcontrol ==false);
    if (tabControl != null) {
      Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(
        function (control, index) {
        if (control.getParent().getParent() == tabControl && control.getControlType() != "subgrid")  {
            control.setDisabled(true);
        }
else {
control.setDisabled(false);
}

    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked it out

```
function DisableAllControlsInTab(tabControlNo)
{
    var factfindcontrol=Xrm.Page.getAttribute("processcomplete").getValue();   
      var tabControl = Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("salesprocess");
   if ((factfindcontrol ==0) &&
    (tabControl != null)) {
      Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(
        function (control, index) {
        if (control.getParent().getParent() == tabControl && control.getControlType() != "subgrid")  {
            control.setDisabled(true);
        }
    });
    }
else {
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(
        function (control, index) {
        if (control.getParent().getParent() == tabControl && control.getControlType() != "subgrid")  {
            control.setDisabled(false);
}
});
}


}
```